# What text editor is available in Heroku bash shell?

Tags: heroku, text-editor

I'm trying to update httpd.conf in my Cedar-based Heroku app. I got to my Heroku bash with

```
 heroku run bash
```

and found the conf dir under apache. But when I try to open any editor vi, vim, or emacs, I can't find any of these programs. How do you edit conf files on Heroku?

Comment: Emacs can [edit files over SSH](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/index.html) :p

Answer (score 131, accepted):

I recently turned the [original gist](https://gist.github.com/naaman/2847793) into a [heroku cli plugin](https://github.com/naaman/heroku-vim).

Just install:

`heroku plugins:install https://github.com/naaman/heroku-vim`

And use:

`heroku vim`

The `heroku vim` command will drop you into a bash shell with `vim` installed on your `$PATH`. All you have to do is retrain your fingers to type `heroku vim` instead of `heroku run bash`.

Comment: when you run heroky vim, I assume you startup a new dyno. Do you know of a way to edit your existing dyno?

Comment: @dwenaus Using vim in a dyno is just a troubleshooting tool. It's not possible to connect to a running dyno. Also, even if you could (you can with a [hack](https://github.com/nzoschke/SSHeroku)), the changes you make inside the dyno would not get persisted inside your slug. i.e. any changes you made would be lost when your app is restarted (every 24 hours).

Comment: @dwenaus another troubleshooting tool you can use -- and I'd highly recommend using this on QA/staging apps, NOT PRODUCTION -- is [`hbuild`](https://github.com/naaman/hbuild). It lets you change your source code without git commits, so you can try out stuff on Heroku without mucking up your git history.

Comment: exactly what I'm looking for. Once in a while there is a Heroku-specific issue and the only way to troubleshoot is via too many commits and deploys - a horribly slow way to debug. thanks!

Comment: Awesome. `hbuild` is under active development. Feel free to file [issues](https://github.com/naaman/hbuild/issues) in its repo.

Comment: Another way to avoid messing up git history is to work in a branch and clean up afterwards before merging into master. If your branch is named `debug-heroku`, deploy like this: `git push heroku debug-heroku:master`.

Comment: Please note we should run `heroku vim` from our local cli, **not** inside the server-side heroku bash shell

Comment: Not sure this is working anymore - yarn exits with 'Refusing to download the git repo .... over HTTPS without a commit hash - possible certificate error?'

Comment: That didn't work, but what worked for me: `heroku plugins:install heroku-vim`.

Comment: Did not work for me. When I try to launch vim after installing the plugin I get `vim: error while loading shared libraries: libXt.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: This answer no longer works with the `heroku-16` stack, as it [no longer has `libxt` available at runtime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack-packages). @funkenstrahlen

Answer (score 63):

If you don't want to mess around with plugins and just want a copy of nano in your one-off dyno, just run

```
mkdir /app/nano
curl https://github.com/Ehryk/heroku-nano/raw/master/heroku-nano-2.5.1/nano.tar.gz --location --silent | tar xz -C /app/nano
export PATH=$PATH:/app/nano
```

This will download a copy of nano from [this plugin](https://github.com/Ehryk/heroku-nano) and put it in your PATH.

Comment: Perfect. Now I can edit configs as needed

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - running nano gives the error `Error opening terminal: unknown.`

Comment: @looeee Working for me still. Are you on the new heroku-18 stack by any chance?

Comment: Working even for Dokku. Thanks @James

Answer (score 29):

there's `ed` if you're a masochist.

Comment: How to exit `ed`?

Comment: in command mode, `q`. if you're in insert mode, print a dot `.` on a line by itself, then enter, to get to command mode. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_(text_editor)#Example

Answer (score 22):

It looks like you can download and install vim for one session:

```shell
#!/usr/bin/env bash
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku-jvm-buildpack-vi/vim-7.3.tar.gz --output vim.tar.gz
mkdir vim && tar xzvf vim.tar.gz -C vim
export PATH=$PATH:/app/vim/bin
```

This idea was found [here](https://gist.github.com/btakita/7853541).

Comment: Just what I needed! Edited a command, ran it. Now heroku can remove my changes over the night, I got my job done!

Comment: See more up-to-date script over there https://gist.github.com/dvdbng/7375821b20f189c189ab1bd29392c98e

Answer (score 15):

Even if you could edit the files with `vi` it probably wouldn't solve your problem because the file system is ephemeral.  Meaning... If you edit a file via `heroku run bash` you aren't actually changing the file for other dynos.  To change a file for all dynos you need to either change what you push in a Git repo or change the buildpack.  More details:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/oneoff-admin-ps#formation-dynos-vs-oneoff-dynos

Comment: I would like to debug the environment from `heroku run bash`, so vi/vim would be very useful for me.

Comment: You can now connect to the actual dyno with `heroku ps:exec`.

Comment: @NicholasMorley You can, but how would you make a site/app notice changes in a file?

Comment: @x-yuri You can't do things that way on Heroku.  You need to redeploy the app to make changes.

Comment: Actually you can. You can take a dyno that's running a site, ssh into it (`heroku ps:exec`), change a file, start a second instance of the server, forward a port to the dyno (`heroku ps:forward 3000`). Then, `curl localhost:3000`.

Comment: You can find a more detailed explanation in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58067826/52499).

Comment: Woah! I didn't know that.  Thanks for the detailed answer and correction.

Answer (score 13):

[The plugin provided by Naaman Newbold](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20691484/10852581) is no longer working with `heroku-16` stack, so I made a new [plugin](https://github.com/jasonheecs/heroku-vim) out of this [updated gist](https://gist.github.com/dvdbng/7375821b20f189c189ab1bd29392c98e).

Install:

`heroku plugins:install @jasonheecs/heroku-vim`

And use:

`heroku vim`

Answer (score 7):

In the comments on the Brian Takita's answer link, there is the more recent solution to get **Vim** working on the Heroku console:

https://gist.github.com/dvdbng/7375821b20f189c189ab1bd29392c98e

Just saved me a lot of time! :)

Answer (score 6):

## Debugging on Heroku

### Prepare the dyno

After installing `naaman/heroku-vim` you can create a new ephemeral dyno via `heroku vim`. As pointed out correctly by other posts you won't be able to see your changes when viewing through the browser because changes won't be propagated, but... you can actually view the changes from inside the dyno itself.

I've only experimented with "browsing" via curl, but if you could get `lynx` on there, or better yet get an ssh tunnel -- could be really great.

### Start the server

The web server won't be running when you instantiate heroku-vim so you'll need to do it yourself. In my example I'm running php:

```
~ $ cat Procfile
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2
```

You can start this command yourself!

```
~ $ vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 2>/dev/null &
[2] 845
```

It's now running in the background!

### curl your website

Dynos start up on random ports. Luckily you know which one because it's the `$PORT` variable!

```
~ $ curl localhost:$PORT
Hello World!
```

### Editing

Do your vim thing now, but when you save the file and curl again - you won't see the changes. I don't understand where it's cached, but it's cached. You have to kill the server and restart it.

### Restarting the server

1. Find the process id

   ```
   ~ $ ps -f
   UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
   u6897        3     1  0 05:34 ?        00:00:00 bash
   u6897      582     3  0 05:53 ?        00:00:00 bash vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2
   u6897      652   582  0 05:53 ?        00:00:00 bash vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2
   u6897      653   582  0 05:53 ?        00:00:00 bash vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2
   ```

   Here `582` is the parent id -- use that.

   ```
   kill 582
   ```
2. Wait just 1 second, and then start the server again (you'll get a new process id!). Curling via the same command will now give you the updated page.

Comment: You can actually [forward a port](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58067826/52499) and use your browser in place of `curl`.

Answer (score 5):

An urgent alternative to edit a file in Heroku:

1. place a copy of it on some remote host. I like to use Gist
2. edit the file on Gist and when finished get the raw URL to it
3. `wget` the raw URL on your Heroku bash
4. copy the fetched file to the path of original file

Comment: I find this solution perfect for a one time need as no plugin is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a complete article on [How to Edit a File on Heroku Dynos using Nano or Vim](http://www.compulsivecoders.com/tech/how-to-edit-a-file-on-heroku-dynos-using-nano-or-vim/), but basically:

- You can use command line:

  `curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku-jvm-buildpack-vi/vim-7.3.tar.gz --output vim.tar.gz
  mkdir vim && tar xzvf vim.tar.gz -C vim
  export PATH=$PATH:/app/vim/bin`
- You can use Heroku Plugins: [heroku-vim](https://github.com/naaman/heroku-vim)
- You can use Heroku Buildpacks: [heroku-buildpack-vip](https://github.com/carloluis/heroku-buildpack-vim)

Hope it helps!

Comment: The plugin didn't work for me: `vim: error while loading shared libraries: libXt.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. But the buildpack did work.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to just view the contents of the file then:

1. cd to the folder where the file is located e.g. `$ cd folder`
2. run cat command + the filename e.g. `$ cat filename.csv`

Answer (score 1):

There are now a number of buildpacks that include vim: https://elements.heroku.com/search/buildpacks?q=vim

You could add one of these to the Heroku app in question, using [support buildpack support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app).

Answer (score 0):

the alternative way if your server run php is to upload PHP File Manager, it single file and you can download it from

`http://phpfm.sourceforge.net/`

Answer (score 0):

One can change files in a dyno and see the result without pushing to Heroku:

1. Install `heroku-buildpack-vim` buildpack:

   ```
   $ heroku buildpacks:add \
   https://github.com/carloluis/heroku-buildpack-vim
   ```
2. Ssh into a dyno:

   ```
   $ heroku ps:exec
   ```
3. Create and run start.sh:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   set -eu
   export DATABASE_URL=...
   bin/rails s -p 4000
   ```
4. Forward port 4000 (second console):

   ```
   $ heroku ps:forward
   ```
5. Open `localhost:4000` in your browser.
6. Stop `start.sh`, change a file, start again, refresh the browser page.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Nano editor, you can use following buildpack...
https://github.com/velizarn/heroku-buildpack-nano