# Rails Application forcing ssl on all calls on Heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application which has a controller with actions which are forced to https and one exception using the following code:

```
force_ssl except: :show, if: :ssl_configured?

def ssl_configured?
    Rails.logger.debug "ssl configured"
    ENV["ENABLE_HTTPS"] == "yes"
end
```

Within one of the views I then have the url defined to access the http link as:

```
place_url(place.id, protocol: 'http')
```

When I run this on my local server (using an NGINX/WEBrick) all actions are redirected to HTTPS except for the show action which is remains unsecured.

However when I deploy to heroku all actions redirect to a secure connection even though the link to the place show action is shown as http.

I have not done any configuration on Heroku (other than setting the environment variable) so the app is running on the WEBrick server.

How can I establish why the exception is being ignored on Heroku? Would I be better starting by configuring a unicorn server as advised in the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#webserver)?

Comment: Could that be a cache problem? That's often a misleading issue I see with those kind of redirect.

Comment: I assume that you mean the browser cache? I'm pretty sure that that is not it. I have cleared the cached web content in firefox. I've also tried Rails.cache.clear on the console returning ["/app/tmp/cache/assets"] (in case that is what you meant). Neither have made any difference.

Comment: I've created a fresh instance of the application on Heroku and it works correctly. This obviously has solved my problem, but I would still be interested in how to investigate the original instance further.

Comment: maybe `config.force_ssl` was set to true?

Comment: Thanks, I'm almost certain that this is not the case. On doing git ls-remote heroku I have exactly the same commit hash against the working and non-working versions and reviewing git config.force_ssl is commented out in both within production.rb. It would be good if there was a way to check the actual files on the server.

Comment: I know this is late but you can actually run server commands with `heroku run`

Comment: thanks @adamk33n3r. I had subsequently found that.... specifically `heroku run bash` allows `ls` to see the files, but these are timed to the load time. There is no built in text editor, but this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666799/heroku-bash-wheres-vi) notes a plugin. I've not tried it though.

Comment: @Richbits I just tried it and it works pretty well. There is no colors but that's ok for a quick fix. If you also just want to see a file and not edit it you can just run `cat`. That will print the file. You could even do `cat file_name.ext | more` and push enter and space to scroll through the file.

Comment: Thanks @adamk33n3r that is pretty good to know. `cat` would have allowed me to check that the version of code.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems as you and couldn't get it working correctly with Rails 4 on Heroku using this method.  So I found and installed the 'rack-ssl-enforcer' gem, which plays very nicely with Heroku.

Just install the gem and add whatever configurations you want to your application.rb file.  The only caveat is that the :except configuration from SslEnforcer was having trouble as well, so I used the :only config and set it to a regex to enforce ssl on the entire site, except for the regex lookaheads "feedback|beta-tester" (these are the routes that I do not want SSL).  Here is the configuration I used:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :only => %r{[\/](?!feedback|beta-tester)\S+}, :strict => true
```

Be sure to set :strict to true otherwise when someone navigates from as SSL page to your show page it will use SSL and vice versa for navigating from a non-ssl.

https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer

Answer (score 0):

Having your application switch back and forth between SSL is bad news, especially *after* a user has logged in. There are extra precautions that need to me made, such as securing cookies. Check out this Rialscasts episode for mode details: http://railscasts.com/episodes/357-adding-ssl.

You would be much better off serving the entire app via SSL.

[/opinion]

As for Heroku, enabling SSL on Heroku will move the app to a secured dyno. Once that is done, *all* requests to that dyno use SSL. I can confirm this behavior. I just deployed to Heroku SSL a vanilla rails app with Devise and `force_ssl` explicitly set to `false`. All non-SSL requests to this app redirect to SSL. This is the Heroku SSL dyno configuration doing this, *not* the app configuration.

So, again, on Heroku SSL *all* requests are redirected to SSL regardless of app configuration.