# How to view and edit files in Heroku bash for noobs?

Tags: bash, heroku, text-editor

I found `cat` and `ed` but they are too tough for me to use. Precisely, `cat` does not view big files whole and `ed` is a single line one! Are there any more ubuntu (humanistic) tools in Heroku bash?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heroku bash - where's vi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666799/heroku-bash-wheres-vi)

Comment: yes, it is. It just didn`t work from the first try. I thought there was solution which does not require extra installing.

Answer (score 4):

You should not be using Heroku to view or edit files directly -- Heroku will delete the files you're working on randomly, **THEY WILL NEVER BE SAVED**!

If you'd like to work on a terminal session, you should instead look at renting a ubuntu server from a company like [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) or [Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/) who specialize in this sort of thing -- or, just install a proper terminal client on your computer.

Comment: There are valid reasons why you might want to edit files. For example, I'm having to run through multiple changes of my Nginx config to try and find a bug. It's very frustrating to have to do a whole build every time I want to try a new setting.

Comment: This is not the right way to do things -- there are other avenues to take to edit files and test things on Heroku -- editing files inline when they disappear will make it impossible to properly test stuff out.

Comment: I need to quickly test around 20 slightly different nginx.conf settings. I don't need these settings to be saved, I just want to pin down a bug. You may say this is "not correct", but that's really irrelevant if it works. 

To be doubly clear, I neither need or want these settings to be saved when my dyno restarts, I just want to be able to test them quickly. Editing files from bash seems like the quickest and easiest way to do this.

Comment: I think the proper way to test that is locally on your box since Heroku is just serving apps via HTTP and using a reverse proxy isn't necessary.