# need to edit template of sitepackages on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

I am new to django and i just deployed my first django site on heroku.

Now my problem is that i have to change one line of code in a template installed through `requirements.txt` in pythons site-packages. Is there a way to upload that one file from my local environment to herokus environment and how could i find the folder structure of my site to upload the edited file?

I thought about making a pypi package but this seems to be too complicated for one line of code…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just run `heroku run bash`

```
cd /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

just one line but vi is not working on heroku so better follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20691484/3762142) and do ...